# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in java

Tags: java, exception, selenium-webdriver

In my java project when am try to initialize firefox driver using selenium webdriver through threads am getting error like this.With out threads it was working fine.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.layoutOnDisk(FirefoxProfile.java:398)
at    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:89)
```

How to resolve this kind of exception

Comment: can you please share your selenium code?

Comment: @Helping Hands:here is the selenium code, public WebDriver getFirefoxDriver(String profileToUse)
 {
  FirefoxProfile profile = null;
  ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
  profile = allProfiles.getProfile(profileToUse.trim());
  WebDriverEventListener eventListener = new EventListener();
        driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new FirefoxDriver(profile)).register(eventListener);
  return driver;
 }

Comment: what you want to achieve via this program?  Something looks wrong in program. Can you please share code in question with proper format?